%%LOCKRES%% - SQL Server - Row identifier causing Deadlocks - possible bug
Recently I came across an issue where I am facing deadlocks in SQL Server databases (19.2.56.2) due to the internal hashing mechanism of the Row identifier virtual column - %%LOCKRES%%
On analysis I find that the row identifier - %%LOCKRES%% generates a hash value with the values of all the columns of the row belonging only to the NVARCHAR data types.
So the scenario where I had deadlocks is when there are two or multiple rows trying to be inserted in different sessions but the concatenated value across the NVARCHAR data type fields of each row insert are same, so internally each of these row insert generates the same hashvalue (LOCKRES row identifier) and when executed parallelly these transactions are deadlocked as it is virtually trying to insert the same row over and over as they have the same row identifier, instead of virtually inserting as different rows.
The below table shows an fictitious example based on real simulations



COLUMN 1 (NVARCHAR)
COLUMN 2 (NVARCHAR)
COLUMN 3(DATE)
Concat of String based fields COLUMN 1 and COLUMN 2
%%LOCKRES%%




AB123.12
1
12/2/2023
AB123.121
5694ad83e25s


AB123.1
21
12/2/2023
AB123.121
5694ad83e25s



Here the concat of Row 1 and Row 2 is same and hence the same LOCKRES hash value is generated.
The hash value changes when I modified the data type to INT for one of the columns and there were no Deadlocks.
This feature has very less documentation so requesting for help on this behaviour and if possible, a solution to mitigate deadlocks in this scenario.

This looks like a bit of an edge case with variable length columns - in that the lockres just uses the binary representation of the index key and apparently takes no account of the column offsets - so it is possible to get this sort of clash without any hash collisions needed.
All of these return the same lockres for example (SQL Fiddle)
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(C1 VARCHAR(20), C2 VARCHAR(20),PRIMARY KEY (C1, C2));
INSERT @T1  VALUES ('AB', 'CD'),  ('A' , 'BCD');

DECLARE @T2 TABLE(C1 VARCHAR(20) ,PRIMARY KEY (C1));
INSERT @T2 VALUES ('ABCD');

DECLARE @T3 TABLE(C1 CHAR(4) ,PRIMARY KEY (C1));
INSERT @T3 VALUES ('ABCD');

DECLARE @T4 TABLE(C1 CHAR(2) ,C2 CHAR(2), PRIMARY KEY (C1, C2));
INSERT @T4 VALUES ('AB', 'CD');

DECLARE @T5 TABLE(C1 BINARY(4) ,PRIMARY KEY (C1));
INSERT @T5 VALUES (0x41424344);

DECLARE @T6 TABLE(C1 INT ,PRIMARY KEY (C1));
INSERT @T6 VALUES (1145258561); -- 0x44434241

But it is only with variable length columns that you can easily engineer a clash in the same index (i.e. easily generate duplicate binary values without causing issues with the fact that every index row has a unique key even if the uniqueifying column(s) are hidden as implicit CI keys or uniqueifier).
Regarding a workaround I guess you just need to find a way to stop these column values ending up with the same binary values when concatenated as the index key.
Workaround 1 - add delimiter
One possible (very clunky) workaround would be to add a computed column to the table that has an expression returning a character extremely unlikely to occur in either C1 or C2. The index could then add this computed column as an additional key column to act as a hidden delimiter.
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
  (
     C1 VARCHAR(20),
     C2 VARCHAR(20),
     HiddenDelimiter AS '~'
     PRIMARY KEY (C1, HiddenDelimiter, C2)
  );

INSERT @T1
VALUES ('AB',
        'CD'),
       ('A',
        'BCD');

--lockres now different
SELECT * ,
       %%lockres%%
FROM   @T1

But the "cure" could be worse than the problem in this case as you would then potentially need to update many queries to include a useless predicate on this new column in order to still use the composite index efficiently.
Workaround 2 - use fixed width column data types (CHAR/NCHAR)
In this case the system will pad out the keys with trailing spaces to fill the length but this could cause excessive storage space requirements (as well as need to RTRIM). If you try and mitigate the space issue with DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW the problem reappears.
Workaround 3 - change index key order
If your queries only ever are doing equality operations on both C1 and C2 and passing both values you could consider whether inverting the key orders would make these clashes less common in the case of your data. But it may well be the case that you require the current key ordering anyway for efficiency of your queries and that this isn't an option.
Workaround 4 - remove uniqueness guarantee
Probably a non starter in that of course it no longer guarantees uniqueness of C1,C2. If the index is non clustered simply not declaring it as unique will implicitly make the CI key/RID part of the key (which is guaranteed unique).
If the index is clustered then the hidden uniqueifier that is added by the system for non unique clustered indexes won't resolve the problem (as this is not unique across different key values) - you could use another clunky solution as below.
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
  (
     C1          VARCHAR(20),
     C2          VARCHAR(20),
     Uniqueifier INT IDENTITY
     PRIMARY KEY (C1, C2, Uniqueifier)
  );

INSERT @T1
VALUES ('AB',
        'CD'),
       ('A',
        'BCD');

--lockres now different
SELECT * ,
       %%lockres%%
FROM   @T1

Workaround 5 - add trailing computed column with column lengths or some other value that depends directly on C1/C2 and can differentiate between cases
This could potentially be the "least worst" option of the 5 I have thought of so far. As the computed column is at the end of the key it is less likely to adversely affect existing queries and this doesn't allow duplicate C1,C2 as workaround 4 would. If you only have two such problem columns then LenC1 would be enough, no need for LenC2 as well. You could also consider BINARY_CHECKSUM to pass multiple columns and avoid this issue. It still ends up polluting the data model though and potentially having unwanted effects if you ever want to reference this PK in a foreign key.
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
  (
     C1 VARCHAR(20),
     C2 VARCHAR(20),
     LenC1 AS ISNULL(LEN(C1),0)
     PRIMARY KEY (C1, C2, LenC1)
  );

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
  (
     C1 VARCHAR(20),
     C2 VARCHAR(20),
     BinChk AS ISNULL(BINARY_CHECKSUM(C1, C2), 0) 
     PRIMARY KEY (C1, C2, BinChk)
  );

INSERT @T1
OUTPUT INSERTED.C1, INSERTED.C2 INTO @T2(C1, C2)
VALUES ('AB', 'CD'),
       ('A', 'BCD');

--lockres now different
SELECT * , %%lockres%%
FROM   @T1

SELECT * , %%lockres%%
FROM   @T2



I find that the row identifier - %%LOCKRES%% generates a hash value with the values of all the columns of the row belonging only to the NVARCHAR data types

The %%lockres%% virtual column returns a hash of the keys for an index row, or the row ID for a heap row.
The format of the virtual column values shown in the question indicates they were obtained by reading from an index, though the value given (5694ad83e25s) is not a valid hash value because it contains the invalid hexadecimal character 's'.
Most likely, you have a (probably clustered) compound index defined on the first two columns. Those two columns make up the index key and only the keys are used in computing the hash. This why only those column values affect the hash value in your example.

I had deadlocks is when there are two or multiple rows trying to be inserted in different sessions but the concatenated value across the NVARCHAR data type fields of each row insert are same

A hash collision on insert wouldn't normally cause a deadlock, though it would cause unexpected blocking.

when executed parallelly these transactions are deadlocked as it is virtually trying to insert the same row over and over as they have the same row identifier, instead of virtually inserting as different rows.

It's not that SQL Server is trying to insert the same row.
In your example, SQL Server decides to lock at row granularity. Both rows to be inserted happen to have key values that hash to the same value, so the second one is blocked when it attempts to acquire a row lock associated with the common hash value.
If your index were currently physically arranged so the two new rows would go on different pages, the two concurrent inserts would succeed using page locking granularity. Both inserts could simultaneously hold the required X lock on the two different pages and no row lock is needed. Without row locks, no row lock hash collision can occur.
SQL Server won't normally lock above row granularity for a single row insert. You would need to override this with a PAGLOCK hint or disable row locking on the index concerned. Of course, this only works if the rows are destined for different pages. You also lose concurrency overall by locking at a higher granularity. It would be like going back to the SQL Server 6.5 days, before row-level locking was offered.
I'm not suggesting you use page locks here. I'm explaining the mechanisms involved.

The hash value changes when I modified the data type to INT for one of the columns and there were no deadlocks.

It is always a good idea to use the right type for the data stored. If the data in the second column is of integer type, store it that way instead of using a Unicode string.
As Martin has partly explained, an index row's lock hash is computed over a binary representation of the key values. Changing the stored format of the data therefore affects the hash value.
Row lock hash
SQL Server's current lock hash is computed using a 64-bit cyclic redundancy check algorithm with a 6-byte result. The b-tree ID (index partition ID) is added to the hash to produce the full descriptor. To get a problem, you therefore need an index key hash collision within a partition of an index.
Since the resulting hash is much smaller than the potential input total key size, hash collisions are always a possibility. Your example is primarily interesting because it is easy for a human to see how this lock collision arose.
One can imagine any number of alternative hashing schemes or tweaks that would avoid the collision in your example. The problem is that locks, especially row-level locks, are taken and released extremely rapidly on a busy SQL Server system. Any internal change that affects locking memory usage or CPU overhead—even by a tiny amount— would have to be very carefully tested, just like the change to using CRC 64 was in SQL Server 2008 R2.
Alternatives
The question is very light on detail, so it is hard to recommend a particular course of action. Aside from Martin's suggestions, you might try using more appropriate data types, as mentioned. If the blocking (or deadlocking) is infrequent, you might choose to let it be and simply retry any failed transactions after a short delay.
On Azure SQL Database, you also have the option to try Optimized locking. This might assist by reducing the number of locks needed and how long they are held.
Additional examples
These examples of a lock hash collision use bigint and integer types only. Row compression is used so the (normally fixed length) values are stored in a variable number of bytes:
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1 
(
    c1 bigint NOT NULL,
    c2 integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (C1, C2) 
        WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW)
);

INSERT dbo.T1 
    (C1, C2)
VALUES 
    (127, 32767), 
    (32767, 127),
    (-127, 515), 
    (-32382, -125);

SELECT 
    C1, 
    C2, 
    [LockRes] = %%lockres%% 
FROM dbo.T1;

Output:



C1
C2
LockRes




-32382
-125
(aaf08ec37ae4)


-127
515
(aaf08ec37ae4)


127
32767
(0000ffffff00)


32767
127
(0000ffffff00)



db<>fiddle demo
